# (How) can i bind my program to different IPs?

Tags: java, ubuntu, groovy, network-programming

My Groovy application is sending some HTTP-Requests and receiving the results using `URL.getText()`. This app is deployed to an Ubuntu server which has different IPv4 addresses.

I'd now like to run different instances of the application on different of these IPs. (How) can i achieve that?

Comment: What's URL.getText()? Why do you think you need to bind to different IP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ubuntu server which has different IPv4 addresses

As I understand on your machine configured several network interfaces (within each network interface your machine has different addresses).

For specifying the network interface for `java.net.Socket` you can use this code:

```
NetworkInterface nif = NetworkInterface.getByName("eth0");
Enumeration<InetAddress> nifAddresses = nif.getInetAddresses();

Socket soc = new java.net.Socket();
soc.bind(new InetSocketAddress(nifAddresses.nextElement(), 0));
soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port));
```

More details in this article http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/definition.html

Comment: Doesn't help when using the URL class.